# does z-index only affect items within the same grouping?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to put something in my html which is located in a different area but has a high z-index so it should be on top.  How does that work?

My example is something like this:

```
<div>
   <div style="z-index: 7000"></div>
</div>
<div style = "z-index: 7050"></div>
```

I was thinking that z-index was only relavent to siblings in your DOM tree.

What do you all think about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This image sums it up nicely.

[image: image taken from the article linked below]

You can find a good article on how z-index property works within the stacking context [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 1):

Yes/No it will only effect things within the same group if the parent element is set to a position of relative. Everything inside of it from that point will inheret based off of that.

From what I see based on your above html however. `z-index` holds no value per say as the elements are not detattched from the DOM flow in a matter of speaking. z-index is for elements that have position: fixed or absolute

example:

```
<div style="z-index:100;"></div>
```

does nothing

```
<div>
<div style="z-index:100;"></div>
</div>
```

does nothing

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;">
   <div style="z-index:100;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:#000;"></div>
   <div style="z-index:200;position:absolute;top:25px;left:25px;background-color:#CCC;"></div>
</div>
```

does something and keeps the elements within the parent div.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
   <div style="z-index:100;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background-color:#000;"></div>
   <div style="z-index:200;position:absolute;top:25px;left:25px;background-color:#CCC;"></div>
</div>
```

does something but the divs with z-index will use the browser as there medium of determining where to place themselves, rather than the parent element.

Comment: Im going to post you a fiddle in a second to see what specifically i am doing wrong, as i seem to be doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

As chris already pointed out, it is important that the `z-index` property only applies to positioned elements. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#z-index) says that the `z-index` property defines the positioning of elements within the same **stacking context**. Not every element generates a new stacking context! Thus, the `z-index` is not only relevant to siblings in the DOM tree, but to every element in the same stacking context. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#z-index) says that elements that have `auto` instead of a integer for the `z-index` property *do not* generate a new stacking context.